# Google Drive API 500 null errors when copying

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I'm getting this error message (100% of the time) when copying a shared file, using the latest version of php library. And I'm getting the same response via the API explorer: developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy

> Google_Exception: Error calling POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/#fileid#/copy: (500) {
>   "error": { "code": 500, "message": null } }

This issue seem to just appear since  3am, 4th Jun 2015 (from Google dev console) and only happening to large files (~1GB). Those files are now showing "Google Drive can't scan this file for viruses." when trying to download it. Google decreased maximum size that it can scan? Is theres any flags like "acknowledgeAbuse" for copy method?

Screenshot API Console:

[image]

Possible duplicate but unfortunately not answered (as of now):  [Google Drive SDK 500 errors on copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392911/google-drive-sdk-500-errors-on-copy)

Comment: Welcome to stack:  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @DaImTo while I do appreciate your efforts, this case is not specific to any particular codes. It could be reproduced on Google API explorer and by many others at https://plus.google.com/u/2/communities/107264319205603895037

Comment: If you need help with code that is not working you should post an example of the code that is not working,  a general error cant help us debug your code.   While I except that you feel that testing with API explorer will also cause the error I suspect that no one will want to do that.  Google API explorer is for testing and timesout often.  It is IMO not a valid example of something that "Should always work".  If someone had spammed it enough it will be shut down until tomorrow.  If your code is causing a problem you should post your code.  again welcome to stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was due to a bug in the Drive API. Here's the canonical issue report:

https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3862

In the future please file issues there instead of posting on Stack Overflow.

The bug should now be fixed.